# I am looking for a website publishing tool lighter than wordpress

Tags: open-source, wordpress, static-site-generator

I want to set up a website for client, who at first only wants to publish some information and then maybe later wants change the text or maybe in the future wants to write a new text. So just for information, design is not very much important, but he wants to be free of any tracking.

So of course, one could install wordpress for this, but I would like to find a lighter and more user-friendly alternative. Maybe something like ghost, but there I could not find a standard design that is without tracking. And I wonder, if there is not even lighter open source tool to use.

I would also prefer a static site generator, but it should be possible to use it in the most common and user friendly way for normal end-users. Because the clients should be able to post and change the contents by their own

Answer (score 1):

You may want to give a try to [Grav](https://getgrav.org/)

It is a static site CMS with a front end admin interface and lot of helpful plugins.

Hope this helps.